# Can not OneToMany target mapped in Hibernate (@OneToMany targeting an unmapped class)

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, target

I am doing a project. I am using hibernate in jboss with maven. However in relation two classes, errors are given.
I added two classes to persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml.
I did'nt use collection. I used set. But errors are given. Why are errors given? How can I solve this problem?

```
 @Entity
 @EntityListeners({ModelListener.class})
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "serviceclass", discriminatorType =
 DiscriminatorType.STRING)
 @ForceDiscriminator
 // @DiscriminatorValue("BASE")
 @Table(name = "infrastructureserviceelement", uniqueConstraints =     
 {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name",                                      
 "infrastructureService_id"})})
 @NamedQueries({
           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.ALL +                
 ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF),
           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.ALL + 
 ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF),

           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_ID + 
 ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF + 
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_ID),
           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_ID +      
 ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF +      
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_ID),

           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_KEY + 
 ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF + 
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_KEY),
           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_KEY + 
 ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF + 
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_KEY),

           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_NAME + 
 ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF + 
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_NAME),
           @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.BY_NAME + 
 ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.SELF + 
 InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.WHERE_NAME)

 })

 public class InfrastructureServiceElementImpl implements InfrastructureServiceElement,      
 Serializable, Alarmed, Monitored {
  @OneToMany(targetEntity = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.class, mappedBy = "infrastructureServiceElement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
  private Set<InfrastructureServiceElementProduct> infrastructureServiceElementProducts = new HashSet<InfrastructureServiceElementProduct>();

  /**
   * Gets the products field of this InfrastructureServiceElement.
   * 
   * @return the products
   */
  public Collection<InfrastructureServiceElementProduct> getInfrastructureServiceElementProducts() {
     if (this.infrastructureServiceElementProducts == null) {
        this.infrastructureServiceElementProducts = new HashSet<InfrastructureServiceElementProduct>();
     }
     return this.infrastructureServiceElementProducts;
  }

  public void setInfrastructureServiceElementProducts(Set<InfrastructureServiceElementProduct> infrastructureServiceElementProducts) {
     this.infrastructureServiceElementProducts = infrastructureServiceElementProducts;
  } 


 }
```

---

```
  @Entity
  @EntityListeners({ModelListener.class})
  @Table(name = "infrastructureserviceelement_product", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                                                                                                              "infrastructureserviceelement_id",
                                                                                                              "product_id"})})
  @NamedQueries({
  /*
                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_ID + ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_ID),
                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_ID + ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_ID),

                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_KEY + ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_KEY),
                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_KEY + ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_KEY),

                 @NamedQuery(name = InabstractfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_PRODUCT_ID + ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_PRODUCT),
                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_PRODUCT_ID + ModelFactory.REMOTE, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.WHERE_PRODUCT),

                 @NamedQuery(name = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.BY_INFRASTRUCTURESERVICEELEMENT_NAME + ModelFactory.LEVEL0, query = InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.SELF + InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl.INFRASTRUCTURESERVICEELEMENT_FETCH + "WHERE isef.id = ?1 AND infsep. = ?2")
  */
  })
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
   //@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert=true,dynamicUpdate=true)
  public class InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl implements InfrastructureServiceElementProduct, Serializable {

     @ForeignKey(name = "infrastructureserviceelement_product_fk_1")
     @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
     @ManyToOne(targetEntity = InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.class, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
     @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH})
     private InfrastructureServiceElement infrastructureServiceElement;


     public void setInfrastructureServiceElement(InfrastructureServiceElement infrastructureServiceElement) {
        this.infrastructureServiceElement = infrastructureServiceElement;
     }

     public InfrastructureServiceElement getInfrastructureServiceElement() {
        return this.infrastructureServiceElement;
     }
 }
```

And following errors are given:

```
    org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.genband.wae.model.entities.InfrastructureServiceElementImpl.infrastructureServiceElementProducts[com.genband.wae.model.entities.InfrastructureServiceElementProductImpl]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1071)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
    at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:301)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:243)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:111)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:263)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hi,
I had tried this. But again I will try this. However It takes 40 minutes code compile. I will write result.

Comment: //@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert=true,dynamicUpdate=true) . I had tried to  this removed comment. But again I will try this. However It takes 40 minutes code compile. I will write result.